# get all table name list into array from sqlite database android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to get all table was i created in SQlite database to string array?.please give me suggestion. Thanks in advance My database class as below

```
private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

   /* public DBHelper(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }*/
   public DBHelper(Context context) {
       super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VIRSION);
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+DB_TABLE+" ("+
                        KEY_ROWID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+
                        KEY_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL, "+
                        KEY_MOBILE+" NUMBER NOT NULL, "+
                        KEY_DATE+" TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DB_TABLE);
    }
}
public MyDatabase(Context c){
    ourContext=c;
}
public MyDatabase open(){
    ourHelper=new DBHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase=ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}
public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this code sample

```
ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();
SqlHelper sqlHelper = new SqlHelper(this, "TK.db", null, 1);
SQLiteDatabase DB = sqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();
Cursor c = DB.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            while ( !c.isAfterLast() ) {
                arrTblNames.add( c.getString( c.getColumnIndex("name")) );
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve question like this code

```
public ArrayList<String> getAllTable() {

    ArrayList<String> arrTblNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    while (!c.isAfterLast()) {

        arrTblNames.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
        c.moveToNext();
    }
    // make sure to close the cursor
    c.close();
    return arrTblNames;
}
```

Comment: how is it different from my answer other than returning the list in the method

Comment: Your Answer is write but i can't understand this line in your answer SqlHelper sqlHelper = new SqlHelper(this, "TK.db", null, 1); , Thanks for your replay. and Both code sucess for my question

Comment: give a checkmark then